# Quando usare "è stato" o "è stata"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, gender

Leggendo un giornale, ho notato questo titolo:

> "Avevamo prenotato tutto // il dietrofront del governo **è stato** l'ultima umiliazione"

È corretto dire 'è stato' lì, o si dovrebbe dire 'è stata'?

Qual è, se esiste, la regola che governa questa struttura morfosintattica?

Grazie.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Entrambe le declinazioni sono valide.

> Il dietrofront è stato l'ultima umiliazione.

- "Il dietrofront" è il soggetto;
- "È stato" è il *verbo*, o più in particolare la *copula*;
- "L'ultima umiliazione" è il *nome*.

"*È stato l'ultima umiliazione*" è un elemento a sé stante detto "predicato nominale". A differenza del predicato verbale, in questo caso il verbo può **concordare** o con il soggetto, o con il nome del predicato. Perciò, è altrettanto corretto dire "Il dietrofront è stato l'ultima umiliazione", e "Il dietrofront è stata l'ultima umiliazione", le due espressioni sono equivalenti (anche nella frequenza di utilizzo, oserei dire).

> La **[concordanza](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/concordanza_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)** è quella regola per cui diverse parti del discorso (in questo caso, 'soggetto e verbo' o 'verbo e nome del predicato') condividono il genere, il numero e la persona.
>
> Per quanto riguarda il predicato verbale, la concordanza può avvenire solamente tra soggetto e verbo. Per quanto riguarda il predicato nominale, questa può avvenire o tra soggetto e verbo, o tra verbo e nome del predicato.

Se si vuole far concordare la copula e il nome del predicato, bisogna fare attenzione in primo luogo a non confondere il predicato verbale con quello [nominale](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicato_nominale), cosa che non sempre riesce facilmente anche ai madrelingua italiani (che pure adoperano questa seconda forma "inconsciamente", senza riflettere se si tratti di predicato verbale o nominale, perchè viene loro naturale).
In alternativa, si può andare sul sicuro e coniugare sempre il soggetto con il verbo. Questa è la *rule of thumb* che consiglierei a uno studente di italiano, perchè consente di costruire più velocemente una frase corretta senza alterare la scorrevolezza del discorso o introdurre forme poco naturali.

Comment: Aggiungo che l'analisi logica è qualcosa che non pratico da anni, e che quindi quella che ho fornito potrebbe essere errata; eventuali correzioni sono ben accolte.